# Remove lightbox behaviour from a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I have an image gallery page, where each image can be "tagged" with multiple tags. Each tag button is displayed on a tab-bar. By default all images are displayed, but when a single tag button is clicked, only images tagged with that tag are displayed.

I'm using jQuery lightBox plugin to display larger versions of images and I would like to see all selected images in the lightBox (by clicking previous/next links).

```
$(document).ready
(
    function()
    {
        // this works ok
        $('#gallery div a').lightBox();
    }
);
```

Everything works great until I filter the images. By default all images are available in the lightBox (and I would like lightBox to have only those filtered images).

I even tried to do this on filter event:

```
$('#gallery div.' + tag + ' a').lightBox();
```

Where "tag" is a string containing only active tag by which the images in the gallery are filtered. This works kinda shady, because the lightBox properly displays only the filtered images, but it has some strange behavior:

- when resizing the box for the next image, animation is a bit messed-up
- image counter displays the first state result (for example 7 of 25), and then the filtered one (for example 7 of 9)

My actual questions are:

- Is there a way to remove lightBox behavior once it has been set on a link?
- Is there an alternative to lightBox, just to be able to "unplug" it easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will disable the lightBox behaviour (as it appears to be nothing but a click event handler):

```
$('#gallery div a').unbind('click');
```

Then, the following works like a charm:

```
$('#gallery div.' + tag + ' a').lightBox();
```